# How to catch android Fragment. onResume() ? or onBackPress

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, onbackpressed

i have 2 fragments of my main layout;

textview from main

**fragment1:**

```
textview="1";
FragmentTransaction fTrans;
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment2);
fTrans.addToBackStack(null); //i tried to delete this and overload onPressBack, but I can't
fTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fTrans.commit();
```

in fragment2 i set `textview="2";` and press **back**, 
i want to cancel all that i've done in **fragment2**, and set `textview="1";`

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: do you want  to reset it to default state of fragment 1 ??

Comment: then initialize all your values in onResume funtion of fragment child class